# Leaflet.js - Set Opacity to LayerGroup with Slider

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I am displaying a leaflet base map. I am using an HTML5 slider to set the opacity to a layergroup but it is not working.

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

```
    <h3>TF.Landscape</h3>
    <br><input type="button" value=" + " onclick="BaseMapAsLayerGroup('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')">
    <br><input id="slide" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0" onchange="updateOpacity(this.value)">

    <hr>
    <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>

    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js"> </script>
    <script>

        var map;
        var capa;

        function BaseMapAsLayerGroup(url){
            if(!map) { 
                map = L.map('map').setView([-41.2858, 174.78682], 14); 
            }

            capa = new L.LayerGroup();
            L.tileLayer(url, {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            maxZoom: 18
            }).addTo(capa);

                map.addLayer(capa);
        }

        function updateOpacity(value) {
            capa.opacity(value);
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to set the opacity of the layer (`capa`) and not the map.  That variable would need to be scoped differently for this to work.  A quick way to do this would be to declare `capa` just under the `var map` at the top of the script.

```
function updateOpacity(value) {
    capa.opacity(value);
}
```

EDIT:

I think this fiddle illustrates what you are trying to do.  There's a couple things that were missing/wrong with the code as it was in the original post including omitting a link to the CSS that is needed for the leaflet library.

[Single Layer controlled by its own slider](http://jsfiddle.net/m13ojymf/2/)

EDIT:

[Two Layers, each controlled by their own slider](https://jsfiddle.net/jasonkoopmans/9c9pq25y/)

Comment: yeah, I want to set the opacity of the layer (capa). I did what you told me, but it doesn't work. (original code is updated)

Comment: works perfect with one layer, but what if I am using two different layers (with different maps) and I want to set the opacity by separate?

Comment: Do you mean:
> single slider changes the opacity of more than one layer (possibly a layer group)
> a slider per layer, each controlling its respective layer

Comment: yeah, that's what I meant. Sorry english is not my native language.

Comment: I added another fiddle.  This one has two independant layers (not a layer group) each controlled by their own slider.  It wasn't clear from your comment which example you were interested in -- I did that one first.

Answer (score 0):

One other way to change the opacity could be to use the `setstyle` function. Hence for your case, try this

```
function updateOpacity(value) {
    capa.setStyle({opacity:value});
}
```